# Error when trying to upload data to firebase using python program

Tags: python, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to upload some data by using json files through python. But I am getting this error and can't resolve. Here is the Python Code. Json files are on separate folders in the same folder.  I just want to ad some categories and items to the firebase using this. Got this code from the Git because it matches with my requirement.

```
Code:

    '''
Uploaded  furniture dataset to firebase

'''

import json
from typing import List
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage, firestore
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

#
STORAGE_PATH = "gs://couchmirage-570ec.appspot.com"
CERTIFICATE = "C:/Users/isuru/Downloads/CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master/CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master/key.json"
DATA_PATH = "C:/Users/isuru/Downloads/CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master/CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master/TO_ADD"


def load_json(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data


def files_in_dir(mypath):
    return [join(mypath, f) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]


def compare_records(doc1, doc2):
    return doc1.items() == doc2.items()


def main():
    # firebase
    cred = credentials.Certificate(CERTIFICATE)
    app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': STORAGE_PATH})
    store = firestore.client()
    doc_ref = store.collection(u'BEDS & MATTRESSES')
    docs = doc_ref.get()
    bucket = storage.bucket("couchmirage-570ec.appspot.com")

    #
    path = DATA_PATH
    items_types = listdir(path)

    for item_type in items_types:
        path = DATA_PATH + '/' + item_type

        items_index = listdir(path)

        for index in items_index:
            item_files = listdir(path + '/' + index)

            images = [item_file for item_file in item_files if item_file.endswith('.jpg')]
            model = [item_file for item_file in item_files if item_file.endswith('.glb')][0]
            collection = [item_file for item_file in item_files if item_file.endswith('.json')][0]

            # check whenevrer uploaded
            exists = False

            item_data = load_json(path + '/' + index + '/' + collection)

            for doc in docs:
                if compare_records(doc._data, item_data):
                    exists = True

            if not exists:
                print("Add:" + model)
                # add record
                doc_ref.add(item_data)

                # # add model
                # fileName = path + '/' + index + '/' + model
                # blob = bucket.blob('models/' + model)
                # blob.upload_from_filename(fileName)
                #
                # # add images
                # for image in images:
                #     fileName = path + '/' + index + '/' + image
                #     blob = bucket.blob('images/' + image)
                #     blob.upload_from_filename(fileName)
            else:
                print("Skip:" + model)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\isuru\Downloads\CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master\CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master\main.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\isuru\Downloads\CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master\CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master\main.py", line 61, in main
    item_data = load_json(path + '/' + index + '/' + collection)
  File "c:\Users\isuru\Downloads\CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master\CouchMirageFirebaseLoader-master\main.py", line 21, in load_json
    data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 114: character maps to <undefined>**
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON file in question is not using the CP1252 encoding. It's using another encoding. Which one you have to figure out yourself. Common ones are `Latin-1` and `UTF-8`.

You can specify the encoding when you open the file. Try something like this:

```
with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```